# Use coordinates from find function to access matrix elements in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix and I am using the `find` function to find all the non-zero elements.

```
[x,y] = find(array>0)
```

The length of both `x` and `y` is 5, but when I do:

```
array(x,y)
```

I get a 5x5 matrix instead of 5 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On way around this would be to use [`sub2ind`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)

```
f = rand(3);
% f = [0.8147    0.0975    0.1576
%      0.9058    0.2785    0.9706
%      0.1270    0.5469    0.9572]

[x,y] = find(f>0.9);
% x = [2;2;3], y = [1;3;3]

g = f(sub2ind(size(f), x, y));
% g = [0.9058; 0.9706; 0.9572];
```

---

Note, this is the same as

```
idx = find(f>0.9);
% idx = [2;8;9]
g = f(idx);
% g = [0.9058; 0.9706; 0.9572];
```

---

You can see (by calling `edit find`) that the "see also" functions include `ind2sub`. The actual `find` function is obfuscated, but this suggests that if you request 2 outputs then Matlab performs an internal call to get `[x,y] = ind2sub(size(f), idx)`, meaning my first example just does the reverse!

**This is why logical indexing is quicker and easier**, there's no faffing around to get the indices correct:

```
g = f(f>0.9);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use logical indexing (usually faster):

```
ind = array>0;
array = array(ind);
```

or simply:

```
array = array(array>0);
```

Comment: This is correct. The difference is that when you put [x,y] = find, it gives you the actual position of the points and not the array of points. That's the difference.

Comment: Yes, i saw that as a possible answer but my actual data is an RGB image, so i want to find for each channel the non-zero elements. Thought it would be easier to get the x and y and then compare each channel.

Comment: @ChristosZS It seems you've oversimplified your example, then. Please edit your question to reflect your actual problem and your desired result.